# MVVM toolkit (templates) and XAML powertoys for wpf mvvm work?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, wpftoolkit

I recently downloaded the MVVM toolkit on codeplex from WPF futures which basically has templates (although i can't seem to find many docs for it) for creating standard MVVM apps for WPF.

I also came across the Powertoys for XAML which allows you to create ViewModels from classes etc..

Is this the best way to go? There seems to be a lot of talk of prism also but this seems to be for creating modular apps for wpf.. and MVVM tookit is an addition to prism

There seems to be so many ways of implementing the MVVM in VS 2008.

I would love to hear some comments or guidance on the best road to take when it comes to doing a MVVM wpf app.

I was looking for a easy (templates) for creating the MVVM wpf app which maybe i should just create an empty wpf project and add everything manually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the greatest learning experience was analyzing the source code of the [Crack.Net](http://www.codeplex.com/cracknetproject) app.

Once again, many thanks to Josh Smith!

Answer (score 0):

I have no specific pointers as to what is the best way to go, and I'm not even sure it is possible to generalize like this without having more context. But I would like to mention Josh Smith's MVVM Foundation:
http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/

It contains some great classes for doing MVVM apps, regardless of which approach you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is beta docs for the datepicker, might be able to find other controls on there too.

Datepicker
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189204(VS.100,default).aspx

Calendar
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar%28VS.100%29.aspx

Datagrid
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28VS.100%29.aspx